# I can't serialize a class created with Fabric JS 5.3.0

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I followed the instructions available on the official fabric JS website: http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3#subclassing. In addition to creating a class, I also want to save and load it, so I also followed the last instruction as well:

```
fabric.labeledRect.fromObject = function(object, callback) {
   return fabric.Object._fromObject('LabeledRect', object, callback);
}
```

However, the problem is displayed in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'fromObject')

Here is the complete code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("myCanvas");


canvas.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
canvas.setHeight(window.innerHeight);

window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    canvas.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    canvas.setHeight(window.innerHeight);
});

var LabeledRect = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {

    type: 'labeledRect',
    // initialize can be of type function(options) or function(property, options), like for text.
    // no other signatures allowed.
    initialize: function(options) {
        options || (options = { });
      
        this.callSuper('initialize', options);
      
        // give all labeled rectangles fixed width/heigh of 100/50
        this.set({ width: 100, height: 50 });
      
        this.set('label', options.label || '');
      },

    toObject: function () {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
            label: this.get('label')
        });
    },

    _render: function(ctx) {

        // make font and fill values of labels configurable
        ctx.font = this.labelFont;
        ctx.fillStyle = this.labelFill;
      
        ctx.fillText(this.label, -this.width/2, -this.height/2 + 20);
      },
});

var labeledRect = new LabeledRect({
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    label: 'test',
    fill: '#faa'
});
canvas.add(labeledRect);


fabric.labeledRect.fromObject = function(object, callback) {
    return fabric.Object._fromObject('LabeledRect', object, callback);
  };


var savedJson;

savedJson = JSON.stringify(canvas);
console.log(savedJson);
canvas.loadFromJSON(savedJson);
canvas.renderAll();
```

Due to the official website being very old, I believe it is out of date, but I don't know how to make it work for the current version.

Comment: I think your question is `how to make it work...` you could refactor that code not use a custom class, Why do you need that custom class?

Comment: You should probably report this directly in FabricJs project: https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues